# ReactJS axios POST call to PHP - Request Aborted error

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a POST call to a PHP file with axios.

```
 loginHandler = () => {

    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('User', this.state.inputUsername);
    params.append('Pwd', this.state.inputPassword);

    var callAction =  process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT + 'LoginHandler.php';

    axios.post(callAction, params)
    .then(res => {
        const message = res.data;
        console.log(message);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

But everything I try seems to give me a "Request aborted" error.
However, doing axios requests from any other component except the LoginForm component seems to work.

Is there anything wrong with my axios call? I just copy/pasted it from a component that works, and it has no issues there.

Comment: Have you tried putting params in json axios.post(callAction, {
    User: this.state.inputUsername,
    Pwd: this.state.inputPassword
  })

Comment: @YatinGaikwad yes, I tried, and I am getting the same error. Think posting the entire file would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method was called on the "Submit" button onClick, which forced the page to reload before the request was completed.

Moving it to the form

```
 <form onSubmit ={(event) => this.loginHandler(event)} >
```

and adding event as parameter on loginHandler, and this line of code

```
event.preventDefault();
```

got it working eventually.